# List.set replacing all indexes inside TreeMap

Tags: java, dictionary, treemap

I have a `TreeMap<String, List<Double>` that I would like to pull out the List at a certain key, add a value at a certain index and then put it back into the TreeMap.

At the time of the below code, the TreeMap contains:

`{specificKey=[0,0,0], specificKey2=[0,0,0], specificKey3=[0,0,0]}`

I want to add the value to specificKey at index 0, so `{specificKey=[777,0,0], specificKey2=[0,0,0], specificKey3=[0,0,0]}`

Here is the offending code...

```
if (myMap.containsKey(specificKey){
    List<Double> doubleList = myMap.get(specificKey);
    doubleList.set(0, someValue);
    myMap.put(specificKey, doubleList);
}
```

Instead, what happens is: `{specificKey=[777,0,0], specificKey2=[777,0,0], specificKey3=[777,0,0]}`

Why is this happening when I am pulling out the exact List with myMap.get(specificKey)? And any ideas on how to accomplish what I need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing everything right. Moreover, you can remove `myMap.put(specificKey, doubleList)`, because the list is already there.

The reason why this happens in your scenario is that all three keys refer to the same instance of `List<Double>` that you created when populating your `TreeMap`. Change the code to insert new lists for each key to fix this problem:

```
myMap.put(specificKey1, new ArrayList<Double>(Collections.nCopies(3, Double.valueOf(0))));
myMap.put(specificKey2, new ArrayList<Double>(Collections.nCopies(3, Double.valueOf(0))));
myMap.put(specificKey3, new ArrayList<Double>(Collections.nCopies(3, Double.valueOf(0))));
...
if (myMap.containsKey(specificKey1){
    myMap.get(specificKey1).set(0, someValue);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have populated the map with three instances of the same list object. You need to create three distinct lists. For example:

```
TreeMap<String, List<Double>> myMap = new TreeMap<>();
myMap.put(specificKey,  Arrays.asList(0.0, 0.0, 0.0));
myMap.put(specificKey2, Arrays.asList(0.0, 0.0, 0.0));
myMap.put(specificKey3, Arrays.asList(0.0, 0.0, 0.0));
```